# How to select all elements except the ones with a given class, using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select all elements in my page except those with the class "searchBox".

How can I do that?

I want to disable text selection on all elements except input elements

Comment: You mean you want to prevent the user from selecting text? Why? That's a terrible user experience. 

If you're trying to keep it from being copied, they can just disable JS or view source to get around that. Don't put it on the internet if you don't want it copied.

Answer (score 6):

```
$('* :not(.searchBox)');
```

`*` : Matches all elements.

`not`: Filters out all elements matching the given selector

Comment: Are you sure about the space between * and :not ? Space is the descendant operator in CSS selectors.

Comment: `$(':not(.searchBox)');` will work almost the same. @subtenante - usually, you are correct, and adding the space is a common mistake. Here it doesn't matter though, because all element are under something anyway (all elements are under `<body>` or deeper, so this version may miss the body tag).